# Groups not working in Google API console

Tags: permissions, google-groups, google-api-console

[It appears](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/) that I can add a group to a Google Developers Console project.

> Project owners *can share a project with an email address that represents a group*, but every project must have at least one project member that is an individual, not a group.
>
> To add a team member or group, select Add Member. You must provide an email address that is associated with a Google account. If the email address belongs to an individual, an invitation flow is triggered, and the new project member must accept the invitation before they can access the project. *If the email address belongs to a group, the group is added right away,* with no invitation step.

However, when I add a group, the project does not appear for members of the that group, and when they go to the URL, they see

> Error The project you requested is unavailable.

Is the documentation out-of-date, is there a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Started working (more than 5 minutes later, not sure how much more).

Likely, the only inaccuracy is

> If the email address belongs to a group, the group is added *right away*